# I would like to learn how to make a folder invisible, but not like changing attributes

Tags: .net

First, let me say thank you to all the people who have helped me. You guy's are great!

Ok, I saw some software that made a folder invisible. I'm not talking about hidden, I mean you couldn't see it at all! Does anyone know how to do that? If you could point me in a direction, that would be cool too.

Also, I'm already doing some things with setting the attributes to "hidden", but that's not what I'm looking for.

thanks.

Comment: If no program can see it, then it doesn't exist for all practical purposes. Otherwise you'll need to be more specific about that other `some software` and what exactly you mean by `invisible, but not like changing attributes`.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Windows API's to directly change its name for another starting with a "not-allowed" character (like % or &). Since deleted file are those starting with "?" (I guess), you could try the same approach.

So, you need to call the low-level function of the same DLL the .NET's "rename" function does.

Comment: What makes you think that `% or &` are "_not-allowed_" characters? Both are perfectly legit characters anywhere in a directory or file name.

Comment: Hey David. That sounds like something I should check out. I haven't done API stuff since VB6 :) I'll start doing some searching and see what I can come up with. Thanks.

Comment: Just a tip. The main idea is the most important (... starting with not allowed character...) and it's just search for them - and they exists.

Comment: % and & are not allowed in names in NTFS. In fact, you can't even create or change a file name to those characters. They have nothing whatsoever to do with deleting files or making them “invisible”.

Comment: Wow... your message came in while was typing mine. From what I know, Microsoft Changes the first character of the file name or folder so it can't be seen and go to the recycle bin. When you "restore" it. They just remove the unreadable character.

Comment: @jumper, try this: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?558058-RESOLVED-Renaming-a-file-using-API

Comment: @DourHighArch `% and & are not allowed in names in NTFS.` Sorry, but that's plain wrong. Please review the pathname rules straight from the horse's mouth at [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx).

Comment: The idea is make a low-level access, under .NET and if possible, under Windows (pure ASM accessing disk-sector can make this).

Comment: @dvix you are right; I though `&` was reserved but it is not.